# How to order by a part of a column

Tags: mysql, sql

i have field with content like this: `1, 2, 100` first two numbers can be any size third one can be up to 100.

Now i need to sort my fields by this third number but since i have 2 other numbers i don't know how to do it.

Maybe i could use something like `REGEXP` or something else?
So far i've tried `SUBSTRING` but since my two numbers can be any lenght something like

```
order by SUBSTRING(my_field, 4)
```

would work but if i have numbers like `32, 451, 30` it takes wrong numbers

Also i use php for to build my query, but i don't think it matters.

Comment: sounds like a bad db scheme...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index). So something like:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(my_field, ',', -1)
```

EDIT: if you have spaces you might want to do some trimming as well.

Comment: additionally, you might also want to try the +0 as @mathematical.coffee suggested.  It's a sweet little trick.

Answer (score 4):

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(my_field,',',-1)+0  ASC -- or DESC
```

Use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index), which grabs the substring up to the nth occurence of the delimiter (in your case, comma), or, in the case of a negative n, it will return the substring *after* the nth occurence from the end.

To see what I mean try:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(my_field,',',-1)
FROM my_table
```

The reason there is a `+0` in the `ORDER BY` is so that mysql sorts these as numbers, not strings.

Comment: the +0 is brilliant, I totally forgot about that little trick!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
order by CONVERT(SUBSTRING(my_field, LOCATE(",", my_field, RIGHT)), INTEGER)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
     SUBSTRING(my_field, 4) AS my_field,
     ... 
   FROM
     ...
   WHERE
     ...
) temp_table
ORDER BY my_field
```